# Problema con login JSON Alamofire Swift 3 iOS

Tags: json, ios, swift3, alamofire

Estoy tratando de bloquear el acceso a la siguiente ventana en mi app cuando el servidor me responda con codigo diferente a `200 (ok)` pero no logro cumplirlo.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usuarioTexto: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contrasenaTexto: UITextField!
var ok : Int? = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fondo.png")!)

}

@IBAction func botonLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    let a:String? = usuarioTexto.text
    let b:String? = contrasenaTexto.text
    let enlace1:String? = "https://" + a! + ":" + b! + "@miservidor"
    print("\(enlace1!)")
    //si usuario esta vacio se manda alerta:
    if usuarioTexto.text == "" {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Usuario vacío", message: "Favor de escribir su usuario", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        //Inicio de sesion
        let enlaceglobal:String! = enlace1!
        Alamofire.request(enlaceglobal).responseJSON { response in
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 200:
                    print("Todo bien")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeScreen", sender: self)

                default:
                    print ("No puede ser!! NOoo")
                }//cierra switch
            }//Lave cierra if
        }//Llave para cerrar JSON
    }//Llave para cerrar else cuando la referencia no esta vacia
}//cierra llave boton accion

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC : homeScreen = segue.destination as! homeScreen
        destinationVC.userName1 = usuarioTexto.text!
        destinationVC.password1 = contrasenaTexto.text!
}//llave para cerrar envio de informacion entre ventanas


}//llave que cierra clase
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque el login sea incorrecto la llamada puede devolver status 200 porque no ha sido una llamada fallida. Donde debes comprobar si el login es correcto o no es en la información que proporciona el json que recibes

Comment: Gracias!! ya pude resolverlo, si me devuelve 400 si el login es invalido.

Comment: Hola! si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera aceptarla clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a ti y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.